# Handle clicks on an element but not clicks on links within that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I handle clicks on an element but not clicks on links within that element?
Say I have the following

```
<div class="section">
    Some text blah blah
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(".section").click(function() {
        // code to expand/collapse section
    });
</script>
```

And I want users to be able to click on .section in order to expand/collapse it but I don't want that to happen if they clicked on a link within that section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the event target, and only do something if it is the `div`. Here is one example:

```
$(".section").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName !== "DIV") {
      //Not the div! 
    }
});
```

You can test various properties of the `target`, so if for example you had other child `div` elements, but didn't want to register clicks on those, you could use the `className` property:

```
e.target.className !== "section"
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekHJH/3/) (using the `tagName` property).

Answer (score 1):

```
var $section = $(".section");
$section.click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).get(0) == $section.get(0)) {
        alert("expanding...");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLMVy/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".section").click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('a')) {
      return;
    }

    // code to expand/collapse section
});
```

`e.target` points to the element on which the user had clicked. So the function checks whether the target was a `a` element. if yes, it just returns from the function

Answer (score 0):

use `return false;` in the end of function